# How to replace String with user input values for storing in a variable?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, replace, user-input

Here is the code :

```
var raw = "{\r\n   \"__metadata\": {\r\n        \"type\": \"SP.Data.TestPostListItem\"\r\n    },\r\n    \"Title\": \"Ankit\",\r\n    \"EmpID\": \"698\"\r\n}";
```

I have two user input values which I want to replace.
**Ankit** with **name** and
**698** with **empid**

I have stored the user input values using useState like this

```
const [name, setName] = useState("");
const [empid, setEmpid] = useState("");
```

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and [edit] your question to include enough context such that we can help you. For instance, where is `raw` coming from? It seems odd that the string has escaped carriage returns and line feeds in it like that. How is Node.js involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to convert your `raw` string into an object:

```js
const obj = JSON.parse(raw);

obj.Title = name;
obj.EmpId = empid;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. But when I was sending to the API it was throwing error. So, I had to convert it to string using JSON.Stringify(obj)